# How to use specific shell during pseudo-tty allocation?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I want to be able to execute remote command in bash instead of default zsh on remote machine (preferable without having to modify settings on remote machine)

Example:

```
ssh -t -t some-command-that-only-works-in-bash-to-execute-remotely
```

Comment: ...see https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sshpty.c -- you'll see it's all in C.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OpenSSH server uses the user's login shell to execute commands. It defaults to /bin/sh if the user's login shell is blank, which is the normal way to interpret a blank value in that field. See `do_child()` in [session.c](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/session.c).

Comment: @Kenster -- I stand corrected. (That said, the "during pseudo-tty allocation" part of the question remains nonsensical on its face).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
ssh user@host "bash -c \"some-command-that-only-works-in-bash-to-execute-remotely\""
```

Please be careful with quoting, however.  The arguments to your `ssh` command will first undergo local expansions and word splitting, then be passed to `ssh`, to then be submitted to the remote shell and undergo a second round of (remote) expansion and word splitting.

For instance, this will echo the local value of `LOGNAME` :

```
ssh user@host "bash -c \"echo $LOGNAME\""
```

This will echo the remote value of `LOGNAME` :

```
ssh user@host "bash -c \"echo \$LOGNAME\""
ssh user@host 'bash -c "echo $LOGNAME"'
```

If you want to understand why, try replacing `ssh` with `echo` and see what command the remote end would receive.

You can also do this :

```
echo "some-command-that-only-works-in-bash" | ssh user@host bash
ssh user@host bash < <(echo "some-command-that-only-works-in-bash")
```

You could issue multiple commands with this method (one line each) and they would all be executed remotely.  Piping the output of a function designed to issue several commands is useful once in a while, as is redirecting a local script so that it can be executed on the remote machine without having to be copied.

Comment: It would be helpful to describe *how* to be careful with the quoting. It's probably not obvious to a user that `ssh user@host bash -c "printf '%s\n' \"\$@\"" _ "first arg" "second arg"` is going to discard the carefully-offered quotes and be equivalent to remotely running `bash -c printf '%s\n' _ first arg second arg` instead of remotely running `printf '%s\n' 'first arg' 'second arg'`.

Comment: (basically, ssh runs `sh -c "$*"` on the remote end, mushing all your separate arguments together, so the `ssh host bash -c "some command that works in bash"` example is outright wrong -- it's much less prone to confusion to only pass a single string in the first place, then: `ssh host "bash -c \"some command that only works in bash\""`, for instance, will behave as expected).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Would you say piping commands instead of using `-c` is likely to require a bit more code, but be easier to understand in terms of what actually makes it to the other end?

Comment: I'm definitely a fan of piping the script from stdin where possible. (A heredoc is perhaps a little more conventional than a process substitution as a means for doing that, btw).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  I do not use heredocs much, because most of what I do is dynamically generated rather than static (or with simple variable substitution only), so that tends to show in the examples I come up with) ; I would normally have a function generating the script, and piping its output to `ssh` with a process substitution.

Comment: As long as it isn't a *quoted* heredoc, these aren't incompatible things; command and parameter substitutions still do happen, thus making `foo <<EOF`; `$contents`; `EOF` a more portable alternative to `foo <<<"$contents"`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  What I often need to do is `foo <<EOF; if [ X ] ; then Y ; else Z ; fi ; EOF`, and of course I cannot do that.  Assembling everything inside a string and then putting it in a heredoc introduces more complexity, so I prefer putting the code in a function, and piping the output of that function to the remote shell with a process substitution.  Maybe the habit of doing that makes me use the technique in cases where a heredoc would be simpler though.

Comment: `<<EOF`; `$(yourfunc)`; `EOF` would achieve the same effect without the need for process substitution.

Comment: Aside from compatibility / POSIX compliance, is there any other benefit?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous comments, here-document can be utilized as such:

```
me@mycomp ~ $ ssh me@127.0.0.1 "/bin/sh <<% 
echo 'user\np@55word!' > ~/cf1
%"
me@127.0.0.1's password: 
me@mycomp ~ $ cat ~/cf1
user
p@55word!
```

From the man page

> The following redirection is often
>        called a “here-document”.
>
> ```
>        [n]<< delimiter
>              here-doc-text ...
>        delimiter
>
>  All the text on successive lines up
>  to the delimiter is saved away and
>  made available to the command on
>  standard input, or file descriptor n
>  if it is specified.  If the delimiter
>  as specified on the initial line is
>  quoted, then the here-doc-text is
>  treated literally, otherwise the text
>  is subjected to parameter expansion,
>  command substitution, and arithmetic
>  expansion (as described in the sec‐
>  tion on “Expansions”).  If the opera‐
>  tor is “<<-” instead of “<<”, then
>  leading tabs in the here-doc-text are
>  stripped.
> ```

Comment: I'd suggest forming the heredoc in the local shell rather than the remote one -- otherwise, the heredoc is created by the remote shell started *before* the explicit `/bin/sh`, rather than by `/bin/sh` itself or the (presumably known/understood) local shell. (Might also want to quote it: `<<'%'` will cause the contents to be passed literally without any expansion or command substitution happening first; otherwise, `$foo` or `$(foo)` will be expanded when the heredoc is evaluated, again *before* `/bin/sh` starts).